# Allow people to click on links under bootstrap modal when modal backdrop is not present

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a very basic page made with Bootstrap.
Using javascript I made an auto-loading modal that appears when the page loads and disappears after 3 seconds. I removed the grey backdrop that usually comes along Bootstrap modals.

What I'd like it for people to be able to click on the text and links that are really placed on the page.

Bascially, while the modal stays open (3 sec), all the links below become unclickable (the mouse becomes a pointer even!)

Here is a fiddle to show you the situation (note that I don't mange to make the modal appear on this jsfiddle while it does work on computer): http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/6808/ (I'd like to be able to click on the button called 'Here is for example a link I'd like people to be able to click while modal is open')

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap 3</a>
        </div>


    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Twitter Bootstrap 3.0</h1>
        <p class="lead">Starter template with CSS and JS included.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="http://yahoo.fr" target="_blank">Here is for example a link I'd like people to be able to click while modal is open</a></p>
      </div>

    <div class="modal in" id="notificationModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="notificationModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="false">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">

        <h3 class="modal-title" id="notificationModalLabel" style="color:#DF2943;">
          How to take part in the deal?
           </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">   
        <h4 style="margin-top:0px">
        some explanations
      </h4>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#notificationModal').modal('show');    
    $('#notificationModal').fadeTo(3000, 500).slideUp(500, function(){
      $(this).remove(); 
    });

  });
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: you need to override the modal's overlay class and set the z-index propety to -1;

Comment: i'm a beginner : how do you remove the overlay ? i thought I was doing it by already putting data-backdrop="false" in my code ; and which class/div should I put on z property=-1 ?

Comment: ohh I see.. then I need to see what html it is generating

Comment: I added the css: .modal-backdrop {
  z-index: -1;
} but I still have the same problem

Comment: note that i don't manage to make the modal appear on the jsfiddle, I don't know why as this part at least works on my computer

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/6808 ... You need to use document.ready

Comment: thanks I updated the jsfiddle. now people will be able to see that indeed i can't click on the button behind it while the modal is open

Comment: the easy fix is setting bottom to initial value, check my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

or just do this

```
.modal{
 bottom: initial!important;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/6811/ run this

Comment: this is the best answer so far as jacking up the z-index of the link on the page is less maintainable, since it will make it harder to stack elements in the future.

Comment: is there a way then to make the modal disappear faster than the 3 seconds if somebody click on the button on the page ?

Comment: indeed instead of a standard button, I am actually loading another modal and don't want two modals  at the same time

Comment: You could add a click handler on the body and close all open modals in that handler, but you would have to make sure that it runs before the handler to open a modal.

Answer (score 3):

Just set `style="z-index: 2000; position: relative;"` for the links you want to be clickable. Without `position: relative`, the `z-index` won't work.

Comment: This will work as well, but jacking up the z-index of the link on the page is less maintainable, since it will make it harder to stack elements in the future.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the modal is taking up the entire width and height of the page, so when you try to click on the link, you are really hitting the modal. You can't fix this with z-index because you need the modal content to be above the rest of the page, but the modal background to be behind it. This is impossible.

The easiest fix is to set the width and height of the modal manually, so it takes up less space and the link is clickable. So in your fiddle add this css:

```
.modal {
    width:500px;
    height:150px;
}
```

And it should work. You can play with those dimensions as you want as well.

Also, to make your fiddle actually show the modal, remove your `$(window).load` wrapper in the JS and just click the Run button.